# How To Initialize Double Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am experimenting with double pointers in ANSI C.

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {


char ** str;

char ** str_zero = str;

*str++ = "Test";

*str = NULL;

while (*str_zero != NULL )
{
  printf("%s\n",*str_zero++);
}
}
```

I am wondering why this program does not work unless I do the following first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

static char * a = "The"; 

char ** str = &a;

char ** str_zero = str;

*str++ = "Test";

*str = NULL;

while (*str_zero != NULL )
{
  printf("%s\n",*str_zero++);
}
}
```

And then delete the static char variable.

Strangely, after deleting static char *a, the first source code works perfectly?!!

How is it possible for the compiler to behave that way?

Comment: To initialize a double pointer: `double *d = NULL`.  To initialize a pointer to a pointer: `void **v = NULL`

Comment: In the first sample, `str` is uninitialised, so using its value to initialise `str_zero`, or all the subsequent things (dereferencing and incrementing using `*str++`, etc) give undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour essentially means "anything can happen as a result of doing this", including different behaviours at different times such as you are seeing. As to why adding and removing a declaration affects anything, that depends on internal workings of the compiler (e.g. faced with a single change that introduces undefined behaviour, the compiler may simply not bother to re-emit object code).

Comment: You may benefit from the write-up in [String not saved in allocated memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996456/string-not-saved-in-allocated-memory/50997846#50997846)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering why this program does not work

Below is your code where I have added some comments that answer the above question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char ** str;  // Now you have a "pointer to pointer to char" variable
                  // The value of the variable is uninitialized

    char ** str_zero = str; // Now you have another "pointer to pointer to char" variable
                            // But you initialize it using an uninitialized variable (str)
                            // That's undefined behavior so from now on anything may happen


    *str++ = "Test";  // Here you make "whatever str points to" point to a string literal
                      // and increment str
                      // As str is uninitialized this is again UB

    *str = NULL;          // UB as str is still uninitialized

    while (*str_zero != NULL ) // UB as str_zero was initialized from uninitialized str
    {
        printf("%s\n",*str_zero++);  // UB as str_zero was initialized from uninitialized str
    }
}
```

Now let's take a look at your second code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    static char * a = "The"; // Now you have a "pointer to char" variable
                             // It's properly initialized to point to a string literal

    char ** str = &a; // Now you have a "pointer to pointer to char" variable
                      // It's properly initialized to point to a char pointer

    char ** str_zero = str;  // Now you have another "pointer to pointer to char" variable
                             // It's properly initialized from another initialized variable

    *str++ = "Test";  // Here you make "whatever str points to" point to a string literal
                      // and increment str
                      // As str pointed to the variable a, the variable a now points
                      // to the string literal "Test"
                      //
                      // As str was incremented it does not point to the variable a anymore
                      // Now str points to a "char pointer" just after variable a

    *str = NULL;      // This is UB. str points to a "char pointer" just after variable a
                      // but you have not allocated a char pointer there so when
                      // you dereference str it's UB

    while (*str_zero != NULL )       // This is ok the first time but once str_zero is incremented
    {                                // it's again UB
        printf("%s\n",*str_zero++);  // This is ok the first time but once str_zero is incremented
    }                                // it's again UB

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I decided the following is a better method of implementing the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

static char * s = NULL;
char ** str = &s;
char ** str_zero = str;

*str++ = "Swiss";
*str = NULL;

printf("%s\n",*str_zero);
}
```

Comment: This is still undefined behavior.

Comment: If you remove `*str = NULL;` it'll be ok

Comment: How about if I replace                                                                                            
                                     *str = NULL;    with *str = s;